# animating the *number* of emitter particle

Tags: texturing, particles, particle-edit-mode

is there a way to actually animate the number of emitter particles? so basically I m trying to make rain first it goes slowly with for example 50 particle , and after frame 200 It goes up to 20000 number of particles , like in real life after a thunderstorm , there will be a lot of rain drops ,when I try to animate the number of particle there is *count properly cannot be animated* is there a way? best regard [image]
edit: the rain particles stops at 400 frames , even though I made it to 500 frames

blend: [image]

Comment: one "cheap" way might be to make the material invisible for some particles. Another way would be that you use geometry nodes or animation nodes which are great for these kind of requirements.

Comment: when i try to animate it oh children simple , the animation looks fine and it worked but for some reason , at like 400 frames the rain stops even though i tried to make it till 500

Comment: i can share my blend maybe can see what i meant ?

Comment: @Gamesnr The keyframe for the children at frame 500 (or actually 499) is not really relevant to the particle simulation because you have set the _Emission_ end frame to 250, so no particles are generated after that.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann yes i forgot that thank you for that , it worked now , appreciated problem solved

Comment: @Gamesnr It looks as if you have a fix, here, which is great. So I think it can be closed as a duplicate without harm. If you want for some reason to reopen, just edit to point out the problem. Thanks.